# ssrs sum the result of a calculated expression

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

[in the red box i have textbox and calculation of the expression. how can i get sum of all the rows in the blue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8DrL.png)

I've tried to `SUM(ReportItems!TextBox258)`

and

`iif(Fields!INvOprCode.Value = 41 AndAlso Fields!invProductID.Value <> 10312 , Sum(Fields!FinalAmountPrice.Value), Floor(Fields!FeePrice.Value * 1.09)*Sum(Fields!QtyConfirmed.Value) - Sum(Fields!AmountDiscount.Value*1.09))`

for the first one i get the last row value and for the second row i get error

eventually i want the sum of red box in all pages to be Shown in the blue page.

the datasets can't be changed because i dont what my data to be change and i need to handle it in the report

Comment: what's the expression in the blue box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but I think the issue is that you are only checking one row for the IIF and then SUMming all the rows based on it. You may need to have the SUM on the outside of the IIF.

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!INvOprCode.Value = 41 AndAlso Fields!invProductID.Value <> 10312,
         Fields!FinalAmountPrice.Value, 
         Floor(Fields!FeePrice.Value * 1.09) * Fields!QtyConfirmed.Value - (Fields!AmountDiscount.Value * 1.09)))
```

On another note, it seems like the discount isn't applied to the quantity - should it be multiplied by the QtyConfirmed?

Comment: I USED YOUR SOLUTION BUT GOT ERROR

Comment: @BehradAfshe - I was missing an ending parethisis. I have added it. If do you get an error, include the error message to make it easier to figure out the issue.

Comment: I GOT THAT OTHER THAN THAT IN CASES WHERE Fields!invProductID.Value = 10312 FOR ALL THE ROWS AND PAGES IT WORKS FINE BUT IN CASES WHERE Fields!invProductID.Value <> 10312 I'LL GET ERROR. I ADDED THE SCREENSHOT AS AN ANSWER CHECK IT OUT PLZ